# Could I create IPA file only with provisioning file in Xcode 7?

Tags: xcode7, ipa

First of all ,I have a `provisioning file` and `p12 file` ,but have not an apple developer account. In Xcode 6, we can create ipa file using command line tool like this:

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive -exportFormat ipa -archivePath $archivePath -exportPath ~/desktop/xx.ipa -exportProvisioningProfile '$provisioningFileName'
```

Could I create `ipa` file using the same way in XCode 7?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rhetorically answering your question - YES.

[xcodebuild](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcodebuild.1.html) will work on Xcode7 and the command you have mentioned is for creating ipa.

Basically you have to give the actual values for that command to work for you.